Get-ChildItem IIS:SSLBindings returns Cannot find drive error, even with WebAdministration and IISAdministration module installed
I am trying to list the current IIS Server Certificates so I can check for expiration dates and etc.
I tried executing the commands Get-ChildItem IIS:SSLBindings and Import-Module WebAdministration but I always get the error message "Cannot find drive. A drive with the name 'IIS' does not exist.".
PS: web-scripting-tools is already installed as a Windows Resource.
The script I created for listing the server certificates was the following:
# PowerShell (PS1)

# Check if the WebAdministration module is loaded and available
if (-not (Get-Module -ListAvailable -Name WebAdministration)) {
    try {
        Write-Host "WebAdministration module not found, attempting to import..." -ForegroundColor White
        Import-Module WebAdministration
        Write-Host "WebAdministration module successfully imported." -ForegroundColor Green
    }
    catch {
        Write-Host "Failed to import WebAdministration module. Ensure IIS is installed and the module is available." -ForegroundColor Red
        Exit 1  # Exit the script with an error code
    }
}

# Verify if IIS:\ drive is available
if (-not (Test-Path IIS:)) {
    Write-Host "IIS drive 'IIS:' is not available. Ensure WebAdministration module is correctly installed." -ForegroundColor Red
    Exit 1  # Exit the script with an error code
}

# Function to list SSL certificates for a specific site by its ID
function Get-SiteSslCertificate {
    param (
        [int]$SiteId
    )

    # Ensure WebAdministration is loaded and IIS drive is available
    if (-not (Get-Module -ListAvailable -Name WebAdministration)) {
        Import-Module WebAdministration
    }

    # Check if IIS drive is available
    if (-not (Test-Path IIS:)) {
        throw "IIS drive 'IIS:' is not available. Ensure WebAdministration module is correctly installed."
    }

    # Retrieve the bindings for the specified site
    $site = Get-IISSite | Where-Object { $_.ID -eq $SiteId }
    if (-not $site) {
        Write-Host "Site with ID $SiteId not found." -ForegroundColor Red
        return
    }

    Write-Host "Retrieving SSL bindings for site '$($site.Name)' (ID: $SiteId)" -ForegroundColor White

    # Get SSL bindings for the site (port 443 or other bindings with HTTPS)
    $sslBindings = Get-ChildItem -Path IIS:\SslBindings | Where-Object {
        $_.Port -eq 443 -and $_.Sites -contains $site.Name
    }

    if (-not $sslBindings) {
        Write-Host "No SSL bindings found for site '$($site.Name)' (ID: $SiteId)" -ForegroundColor Red
        return
    }

    # List each binding's certificate thumbprint
    foreach ($binding in $sslBindings) {
        Write-Host "`nSSL Binding: Port $($binding.Port)" -ForegroundColor Yellow
        Write-Host "Certificate Thumbprint: $($binding.Thumbprint)" -ForegroundColor Yellow
        
        # Retrieve the certificate from the local machine store using the thumbprint
        $certificate = Get-ChildItem -Path Cert:\LocalMachine\My | Where-Object {
            $_.Thumbprint -eq $binding.Thumbprint
        }
        
        if ($certificate) {
            Write-Host "`nCertificate Details:" -ForegroundColor Cyan
            Write-Host "Subject: $($certificate.Subject)" -ForegroundColor Cyan
            Write-Host "Issuer: $($certificate.Issuer)" -ForegroundColor Cyan
            Write-Host "Thumbprint: $($certificate.Thumbprint)" -ForegroundColor Cyan
            Write-Host "Expiration Date: $($certificate.NotAfter)" -ForegroundColor Cyan
        } else {
            Write-Host "Certificate with thumbprint $($binding.Thumbprint) not found in the local machine store." -ForegroundColor Red
        }
    }
}

# Call the function for Site ID 5
Get-SiteSslCertificate -SiteId 5

And the output was:

WebAdministration module successfully imported.
IIS drive 'IIS:' is not available. Ensure WebAdministration module is correctly installed.

Any help is appreciate it.

You have to run powershell as administrator.  You can run Import-Module WebAdministration -Force and see if you get any errors.

Do you have any local policy or domain policy on this machine that prevents or restrict drives such as 'Prevent access to drives from My Computer' or 'Hide these specified drives in my computer' ? They might be blocking the access to IIS: drive from powershell.

A similar case you can referred: Getting "Can't find the drive. The drive called 'IIS' does not exist.", The main possible reasons are the import of modules and the permissions of executing scripts, please check them.
